# Passing arguments to `caller` statement in `raise` statement

Tags: ruby, exception, raise

I cannot follow what `caller` does in these exception raising statements.

```
raise InterfaceException , "Error", caller

raise ArgumentError, " Error", caller[1..-1]
```

I know that `Object#caller` sets and sends stack trace to upper level in hierarchy. What is the interpretation of the arguments `1..-1` of the method `caller`?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Object#caller`. `1..-1` is not argument**s**, it is a single `Range` argument.

Comment: @sawa: Well, technically, objects _do_ respond to `caller`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Right, but is that what `Object#caller` means?

Comment: @sawa: I think it is. The fact that actual implementation is inherited is not very relevant. People say stuff like `User#create` all the time, despite the fact that the implementation resides somewhere in the bowels of active record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, `caller` returns current stack trace (not including current method). `caller[1..-1]` returns the stacktrace, minus its first entry.

Might be useful in some situations. For example you set up a params validation handler (or whatever) and it can raise. But you don't want to see the error originate in the validation handler. You want the line that called it.

Comment: using `caller` will exclude the current method from the stack trace you'd see if you just did plain old `raise InterfaceException, "Error"` and so using `caller[1..-1]` will be removing the top 2 entries from the default behaviour.

Comment: @mikej: yes, you're correct. Realized that after running wandmaker's code. The idea is still the same: ignoring last elements of the stacktrace. Sometimes you skip one line, sometimes more.